# How can I get the computers to stop pestering me?

Tags: civilization-5

I enjoy playing domination matches on huge maps with 22 computers, the only part I don't like is being pestered every turn by a dozen requests. Whether its friendship requests, begging for gold or telling me I'm a war hungry monster. I want it all to stop, just go about on my war rampages. I know computers don't bother you when you make a multiplayer game, unfortunately you can't play with more than 12 players. At least, from what I could tell when creating one.

**So is there anyway to block the computers from talking to me completely?**

Comment: Curious, which civ do you prefer for such rampages?

Comment: @Katustrawfic Germany or Russia.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not. The closest solution is an Embargo via the World's Congress/United Nations, but that only applies to trade routes, not direct trade transactions, and really does not apply to your case.

Comment: If you can do it in multiplayer i dont see why it is impossible in single player.

Comment: @Paralytic That is because in multiplayer, the AI is engineered to not approach the player with deals (or threats, etc). This behavior is unique only to multiplayer, however.

Comment: just seems unlikely that no one has duplicated the settings of multiplayer